# Actor origin in scene 2d

Tags: libgdx

I don't seem to understand the actor origin in scene2d of Libgdx correctly.

My understanding is as follows:

If I setX of an actor to 0, its left edge is going to be rendered at corrdination 0. Now if I set its origin's X to 5, the fifth pixel of the actor is going to be at corrdination 0, in other words, the left edge of the actor is going to be at -5.

Some how my experience shows otherwise. If I set origin to 5, the left edge somehow is rendered on coordination 5.

Can someone please help me understand this issue.

Answer (score 4):

the `origin` is used only for scaling and rotation.
That means, that if the origin is P(0,0) (the default), the `Actor` will be rotated and scaled arround his lower left corner.
If you instead set it's origin to the center (P(width/2, height/2)), he will rotate and scale arround his center.
The position instead is always relative to the lower, left corner and is not affected by the origin.
If you want to set the `Actor`s position relative to his origin, you need to use the origin as offset:

```
actor.setX(newPosX - actor.getOriginX());
actor.setY(newPosY - actor.setOriginY());
```

Also remember, that setting an x-origin of 5, like in your example, does not need to set the `Actor`s origin to it's 5th pixel, but to it's 5th unit.
If you use a `Viewport`, you don't need to calculate things in pixels, which is really important, as you can support different resolutions and aspect ratios.

Comment: The problem is, the position is affected by origin in my setup. I do not use any layout with scene2d, and it is used only for eventing etc. In my application, when I change the origin, it changes the origin of image/actor.

Comment: BTW, I tried setX and setY. But there is a problem when you combine it with actions. MoveToAction does a getX and setX on its actor, with this implementation of setX, this two consequent has an undesirable effect of changing the location of actor.

Comment: @Arash in your case the origin does affect the position? Thats really strange as the doc of `Actor` says: "The origin is relative to the position and is used for scale and rotation."  Also the `setOrigin` does not set the position of the `Actor`. For your second comment: The code in the answer is only an example. To use it with `Action`s, you should just change the destination point of the `Action` with the `origin` in mind.

Comment: @springrbura I know it is strange, but it does effect the location of my Actor. Looking at the code, it seems it should actually. I ended up overriding the draw method of the Image to fix the problem